# Como almacenar datos de una petición en el dispositivo

Tags: swift

Estoy utilizando un webservice para poder hacer la aplicacion en iOS. Se inicia sesión con legajo y password y te devuelve un hash que sirve tambien para iniciar sesión.

La idea es, iniciar sesión y guardar ese hash en el dispositivo, asi al seguir haciendo peticiones al webservice no hay que escribir los datos.

Por ahora hice esto que es para iniciar sesion, tengo que manejar la respuesta y ver como guardar los datos.

```
import Foundation

class LoginViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var legajo = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    
    init() {}
    
    func login() {
        guard validate() else {
            return
        }
        
        // Try log in
        let url = URL(string: "https://webservice.frvm.utn.edu.ar/autogestion/login")!
        
        // Create request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // Add nick and password on headers
        request.addValue(legajo, forHTTPHeaderField: "nick")
        request.addValue(password, forHTTPHeaderField: "password")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Error en la solicitud: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Desconocido")")
                
                // Show error
                
                
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func validate() -> Bool {
        errorMessage = ""
        guard !legajo.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              !password.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            errorMessage = "Llenar todos los campos, por favor."
            return false
        }
    
        
        return true
    }
}
```

La peticion POST en el webservice, que se pasa legajo y password por headers, devuelve el siguiente json:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "nick": "14700",
    "grupo": null,
    "persona": null,
    "hashActual": "hashoculto"
}
```

Comment: Si solo quieres guardar el hash, puedes usar el [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain) para almacenar de manera segura en el dispositivo, si has escuchado sobre  `UserDefaults` también sirve pero no es recomendado para datos sensibles.